# How to make persistent a python dictionary on google appengine

Tags: python, dictionary, persistence

Using datastore framework of appengine, what's the pythonic way to make persistent a {}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 options.

1. Using expando. You can store anything in that as long as you omit the reserved fields:

   ```
   class SomeModel(db.Expando):
       pass

   your_model = SomeModel()
   for k, v in your_dict.iteritems():
       setattr(your_model, k, v)
   ```

   It might be possible to use `your_model.__dict__.update(your_dict)` but I'm not sure about that.
2. Store it in a textfield using pickle:

   ```
   class SomeModel(db.Model):
       pickled_data = db.BlobProperty()

   your_model = SomeModel()
   your_model.pickled_data = pickle.dumps(your_dict)
   ```

Comment: If you use the custom property, you don't need to explicitly unpickle the value every time you want to read it. No problem re. the link :)

Comment: Indeed, your option is much more elegant :) +1

Answer (score 5):

You would only need to use the expando option if you intend to query on the individual dictionary elements.

Assuming you don't want to do this, then you can use a custom property -

```
class ObjectProperty(db.Property):
  data_type = db.Blob

  def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
    value = self.__get__(model_instance, model_instance.__class__)
    pickled_val = pickle.dumps(value)
    if value is not None: return db.Blob(pickled_val)

  def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    if value is not None: return pickle.loads(str(value))

  def default_value(self):
    return copy.copy(self.default)
```

Note that the above property def I got from some code that Nick Johnson produced. It's a [project on git hub](http://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/), and contains a number of other custom properties.

Answer (score 3):

You should store it using pickle.dumps and retrieve it using pickle.loads

see
 http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html